# How much bytes is a double in an array and char in an array?

Tags: c++, memory, byte

So every element in an array is 4 bytes. And every double takes up 8 bytes. So does a double in an array also takes 8 bytes?

Similarly, char is 1 byte. So is a char in an array just 1 byte?

Comment: Which language? Java defines its own virtual machine, a bit too specified. In general your assumption is not true. In Java 4 bytes is the "word" size of a location and byte, char (2 bytes), short are also kept in 4 bytes. However an array of bytes not. And an array of doubles also not.

Answer (score 1):

> So every element in an array is 4 bytes.

That is incorrect.  Every element is the same size as the array's element type.  The total size of an array of `N` number of `T` elements is `sizeof(T) * N`.

> every double takes up 8 bytes. So does a double in an array also takes 8 bytes?

Yes.  So, if you have an array of 5 `double`s, for instance, then the array is `sizeof(double)*5 = 8*5 = 40` bytes in size.

> Similarly, char is 1 byte. So is a char in an array just 1 byte?

Yes.  So, if you have an array of 5 `char`s, for instance, then the array is `sizeof(char)*5 = 1*5 = 5` bytes in size.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on your programming language,if you mean the C language,differ type of array will cost differ usage.
You can check it using the `sizeof()` operator

```
char x[] = {'p','c','n','o','p','r','o','b','l','e','m'};
printf("％d", sizeof(x));

return 0;
```